# Sass compilation error (underfined variable)

Tags: sass, compiler-errors, compilation, live-sass-compiler

I'm trying to compile a Sass file

The root file looks like this

```
@use '_colortheme'
@use '_config'
@use '_datepicker'
@use '_main'
```

In partial `_main` I'm trying to use variables from `_colortheme` and `_config` but get the error for all the variables

```
Compilation Error
Error: Undefined variable.
```

I'm new to Sass, have tried `@use` and `@forward` in partials, but didn't work.
What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: How have you tried to reference the variables? Consider providing an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you didn't call the variable correctly using `@use`. As stated in the official [SASS documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/#loading-members):

> You can access variables, functions, and mixins from another module by
> writing `<namespace>.<variable>`, `<namespace>.<function>()`, or
> `@include <namespace>.<mixin>()`. By default, the namespace is just
> the last component of the module’s URL.

Wrong:

**_main.scss**

```
@use 'colortheme';

.my-class {
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

Correct:

**_main.scss**

```
@use 'colortheme';

.my-class {
  color: colortheme.$primary-color;
}
```

Comment: The `_` in the import and namespace is not required.

Comment: @Arkellys Correct, my mistake. I edited my answer.